# Multi-user PHP App with mySQL database - Different Users Same Tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Just a quick question - I am writing a PHP app that relies heavily on SQL databases.  I am slightly worried that many users all accessing the same database will cause errors.  If so, how can I overcome this, what can be done?

I am not sure how many users at the end of the day will be using it, not hundreds, but maybe 5 or 10 or even 20.  And even then its unlikely that they will be updating at the EXACT same time, but still.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of errors are you expecting?

Comment: Well I just wonder what exactly happens if say two people update the SAME table at exactly the SAME time, surely that would produce an error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524182/what-would-happen-if-2-or-more-people-attempt-to-update-the-same-mysql-table-at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399191/web-inserts-at-the-same-time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099890/2-users-updating-a-record-at-the-same-time

Comment: Database servers handle concurrency access, reading/writing lock. Don't worry :)

Comment: so the solution.. is locking the tables? it seems to say that mySql is very good at preventing deadlocks?

Comment: @FrancoisB. So I dont need to modify my SQL then to LOCK tables? It should do it by itself?

Comment: is the question to update different rows in the same table or update the same row in the same table? - updating different rows at absolut the exact same time is 100% not a problem - this is a default usecase for database server, updating the same row at exactly the same time is a bit tricky and here locking would be a good idea. BUT if you lock for user A and user B is writting something you should say user A that there is a change - thats the tricky part

Comment: As proposed by **Struna**, use MySQL's transactions and some OpenSessionInView pattern: at the beginning of the request (http request), open a transaction, do the job, then commit if ok/rollback if error, and close the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html) is what you're looking for.
Then PHP [PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with its [transactions management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah but i'm saying, there seems to be two thoughts: one is, with mySql its not needed, it handles concurrency in its own way, and two, start locking your tables.  So which is it?

Comment: Oh yes, it's needed with MySQL. By default it does not handle the concurrency the safe way. This is why transactions are provided where there's a need. There's another question on SO that may answer your question: [mySQL Transactions vs Locking Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226766/mysql-transactions-vs-locking-tables).